# MVC confusion, where do I put my model?

Tags: arrays, cocoa, model-view-controller, model

I'm working on my first cocoa app from scratch and I'm a little confused about how to get my model, view, and controller working together. I'm sure I'm just missing something inane.

Basically, my view is currently set up to return 3 values to the controller. The controller takes those values and creates a new instance of a class. I want to be able to put those objects in an array and then work with the array.

First: The array I want to create... it is my model, right? How and where do I create it so that an action in the view (inputing the values) is interpreted by the controller correctly (creating the object) and then stored in the method?

Second: The attempts I have made leave me isolated from my array. I tried to create a class for the array, but I can't access it from the controller. How do I get around this?

Lastly: I've been banging my head against the code for a few days. I'm teaching myself and I'm learning a lot but I have lots of simple questions like this. Thank you for taking the time to help. )

EDIT:

I've created the Student class. The Action sends the values to the controller and the controller creates a new instance:
`- (IBAction)addNewStudentButtonPressed:(id)sender

{

    Student *newStudent = [[Student alloc] initNewStudentwithName:[nameField stringValue]

                                                            andID:[idField intValue]

                                                         andLevel:[levelField stringValue]];

}`

The Array is being created in the `appDidFinishLaunching` method:
`-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification

{

    NSMutableArray *roster = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];

}`

And now I want to add the student to the array. I'm just missing something obvious. :(

Comment: Give us some code example so we can help you ^^

Comment: You just need to make roster be an instance variable of the controller and add the student to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the **model** as an active representation of what your program is dealing with - you need to show a list of students? Then you have to design a `Student` class with a bunch of properties [like I smell you already did].

The **controller** acts as a bridge between the user and the model, and this connection is the **view**: you hit a button in the view, and you want a new student to be created therefore, and to be added to an array then.

First, you need an array: you provide your Controller with such property/ivar - I'll stick with ivar in this example:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{

    //this is the array you will deal with inside Controller methods
    NSMutableArray* students;

    //you probably have some IBOutlets here:
    IBOutlet NSTextField* nameField;
    IBOutlet NSTextField* idField;
    IBOutlet NSTextField* levelField;

}
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    students = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];

}

- (IBAction)addNewStudentButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

    Student *newStudent = [[Student alloc] initNewStudentwithName:[nameField stringValue]
    andID:[idField intValue]
    andLevel:[levelField stringValue]];

     //now you add the student to the array
    [students addObject: newStudent]

}
```

The array is part of the logic, but not of the model itself - it's just a controller basic field at the moment. Of course if you define a `Classroom` class with a list of students, you are wrapping the array inside another entity.

Anyway the MVC matter is quite loose, and has many implementations - don't let it overhelm you, just let the pattern help you to separate concerns and to have a smoother development, but don't think of it as a dogma.

Comment: This really helped me. in my `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method i was initializing a pointer (I think) `NSMutableArray = *roster` instead of just working with it. )))

Comment: Yes, your `roster` var would die at the end of the method, and it won't be accessible anytime after - defining it as an ivar, it lives till the containing class is alive.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you seem to be asking mainly whose responsibility is the container into which your model objects are stored. This is one of those gray areas that could cause a lengthy discussion but the easiest thing to do is consider it part of your model. This is because, most likely, you'll want to persist your model at some point and, rather than create one file per item, it's more likely you want to just stream the whole container out to a file and back again.

So, who controls this? If you have a document-based app, your NSDocument subclass does. It's a "Model-Controller" (which covers that gray area nicely). You'll override the methods provided to write and read the file format you decided on, which can be as easy as using NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver to read/write the whole array (or dictionary or other container). The document instance keeps the container around and adds Student instances to / removes from as your UI commands.

In a non-document-based app, someone needs to keep this container so this is a question of architecture. The simplest way is to stash it into your app delegate instance and provide paths to get to it that way (accessor methods, etc.) from other parts of your app. The "better" solution is to have a "StudentController" object that manages the array of students. When you're more comfortable, take a look at Cocoa Bindings and NSArrayController. It can simplify some things an complicate others, but its design is the basic idea. Sans bindings, however, your StudentController object will hold the container (array) and handle -addStudent: -removeStudent: as well as "archive/unarchive" functions, however you want to handle them. This way, your StudentController becomes the central store manager for all students, wherever the container lives (file, database, whatever).

Using Core Data makes this even easier in the basic case. You define your data model (a single entity named Student) and can create / insert / edit students all without any code at all. Core Data and Cocoa Bindings takes care of everything behind the scenes by using some of the architecture I described above and some I haven't.

More specific questions get you more specific answers. :-)